# Display images from other drive on Coldfusion

Tags: html, image, coldfusion

My coldfusion webpages are in D: drive and need to display images on webpages from
E:\Photo\ drive. I have done mapping for location E:\Photo\ with the logical path name \Photo on CF admin. for example

```
<img src="\Photo\one.png" >
```

but it does not work.

Please suggest.

Comment: CF mappings are only for use by the CF engine on the server. The browser responsible for interpreting the HTML produced by CF doesn't have access to CF mappings, nor can it retrieve information from your server that isn't in the webroot.  If you want to do something like this, you can redirect missing image requests (404s for .png, .gif, . jpg etc) at the webserver level to a CF page that will interpret the image request, retrieve the image file (from the mapped folder) and return it to the browser as an image using cfheader and cfcontent.  This may be more trouble than it's worth. :)

Comment: The `cfimage` tag may be of use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used the cfimage tag before, but I was curious.  This cf code:

```
imagePath = "d:\dw\dwweb\gifs\help_access1.bmp";
</cfscript>
<cfimage action="writetobrowser" source="#imagePath#">
```

Displayed the image in the browser.  The resulting html was:

```
<img src="/CFFileServlet/_cf_image/_cfimg-5484608367029654370.PNG" alt="" />
```

Comment: Great, Many Thanks Dan.

Answer (score 5):

This is a fairly simple task that is set up on the web server (IIS?).  ColdFusion is not involved.

You need to set up a virtual directory called "Photo" and have it point to the directory on your E drive.  Users and their browsers will be none the wiser.

Comment: My vote put your reputation into triple digits.  You owe me a beer.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but client's IIS is beyond my approach.